# Why do i get the npm error -38 when trying npm install?

Tags: docker, npm

Hi i am trying to run the command like below

```
docker run --name authservice --network=something --ip=someip -v "$(workingDir)/src/":/app/ -p 
3000:3000 \
--entrypoint bash $imageName -c 'npm install && npm run start:dev'
```

and i get the error below

```
npm ERR! code ENOSYS
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -38
npm ERR! ENOSYS: function not implemented, read
```

I am not sure what causes this. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: Can you include your image's Dockerfile?  You shouldn't need to bind-mount your application code in, run `npm install` at startup time, or override `--entrypoint`; all of this should be set up correctly in the image for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try restarting your docker services.

Answer (score 0):

tried to restart / rebuild multiple times, didnt work
I m getting this error when doing composer install after a fail in docker

include(): Read of 678 bytes failed with errno=38 Function not implemented